# Macbook Pro two external display, one keeps blinking/turn-black

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I recently set up 2 external displays to my MacBook Pro, 2017. 1 monitor is a Samsung 27" 4k, the second one is Dell 28" LCD.

The Samsung is connected with [this adapter](https://www.amazon.com.br/dp/B07X25ZR56?ref_=pe_7178540_378349570_dpLink) and another [one with this](https://www.kabum.com.br/produto/102843/hub-usb-5-7x1-ubs-3-0-leitor-de-cartoes-sd-micro-sd-hdmi-rj45-usb-c-018-7453-?gclid=CjwKCAjwqJ_1BRBZEiwAv73uwAwuYVKJUmBDOkz36r1xYfCZ3hUnsaLqS1bOS983tMvYk3_hroR9UxoCkUIQAvD_BwE).

The Samsung display works perfectly, no issue at all. But the Dell, from time to time turns to black or starts to blink and eventually turns to black as well. In the end, I need or remove the cable from the MacBook or turn the display off and turn it on again.
Any idea how I can handle this issue?

If more information is needed I will be happy to provide it.

Computer info:

MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports, 16 GB RAM)
OSx version: 10.14.6

Thanks in advance

UPDATE 11.2.1 the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE to 11.2.1 to fix the issue.